# Presenter having Handler in Android MVP pattern

Tags: android, android-mvp

Is it okay a presenter having Android Handler?
I know presenters should not have any Android related objects,
but I really don't have any clear answer.

Here's the thing,
this presenter runs a disk IO task on another thread,
meanwhile, the activity has to change its view.

These jobs are supposed to be done concurrently.
So I decided to pass the activity's handler as an argument 
and let presenter send message to activity like this:

```
class FooPresenter: FooContract.Presenter {
    …
    private fun doDiskIOTask(handler: Handler) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0)
        do_something_on_new_thread_and_join()
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1)
    }
    …
}
```

The activity has to know when the task is started and finished both and change view.
Could you tell me if I'm doing it any wrong or the better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `Handler` to the presenter doesn't sound like a good idea, you wouldn't be able to unit test it. I think a better approach would be to just call a method on the view and then run on UI thread from there. If your view interface is an `Activity` you can use the very convenient `runOnUiThread` method, e.g.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity, FooContract.View {

    override fun emptyMessage0Method(){
        runOnUiThread { 
            // manipulate views here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we have an easier  method for this? Actually there are a lot of methods in my activity and writing runOnUIThread() for all will not be good idea. is there any way to make all views thread safe ..

Comment: @ManmohanSoni I think that methods in an Activity should always been called on the main thread moving all asynchronous work in the presentation layer. There shouldn't be any need for multi-threading at the View layer

Comment: yes the same thing i want to achieve. I just want every update sent by the presenter to the view must be on main thread not on any other thread. But until i got any other solution for this i need to use runOnUiThread for now.

Comment: @ManmohanSoni I would focus on why you have methods of the Activity called on non-main thread, RxJava can provide a very convenient way of designing the whole thing.